# Laravel Eloquent model's mutated/appended attributes

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I want to fetch mutated/appended attributes of laravel eloquent model. I tried `$model->getAttributes()`, but it returns array of raw attributes as they are stored in database. But I want to fetch the changed attributes as well, which are not yet saved to the database.

I tried `$model->toArray()`, it returns the array of raw and mutated/appended  attributes. But converts value of 'date' field to string.

I am using mongodb as database. The 'date' is saved as mongodate, but `toArray()` converts it to string - "date" : "2011-03-23 12:00:00" .

So when I try to save these mutated/appended attributes fetched from `toArray()` to database, my date gets saved in string.

Is there any other way to fetch eloquent model's mutated/appended attributes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to re-use Eloquent's logic of serializing models to arrays but to skip that part of the logic that serializes dates to strings.

Eloquent recognizes the date fields by checking if their name is returned from `getDates()` method of your model. Overwrite that method so that it returns empty array and dates won't be serialized.

The reason why you need to overwrite `getDates()` instead of just setting `$dates` attribute to an empty array is that `getDates()` in addition to what is defined in `$dates` also returns `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I need to return 'date' field from `getDates()` method, because of other dependencies. Is there any other way to skip date serialization to strings?

Comment: There are other ways, but they require some coding/hacking - what you're trying to achieve is in between 2 ways of representing models that Eloquent provides - non-serialized model and a model serialized to array. You might return "date" from getDates and define a getter for "date" that would unserialize the field. You might just add setters for all dates that would convert strings to Carbon objects. You  might overwrite toArray method in your objects ... Not sure what will be best for you as I don't understand why you want to save array-serialized object in Mongo instead of the plain object

Comment: Thank you. I will try those.